# I'm trying to develop an RVIZ plugin and I've error like this one presented in the question below (link). Can someone help me?

Tags: rviz, plugin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Link to question:
http://answers.ros.org/question/276894/launch-a-new-rviz-plugin-failed-errorfailed-to-load-library-xxxsomake-sure-that-you-are-calling-the-pluginlib_export_class-macro-in-the-library-code/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326576/i%27m-trying-to-develop-an-rviz-plugin-and-i%27ve-error-like-this-one-presented-in-the-question-below-(link).-can-someone-help-me?/) by [Hillal](https://answers.ros.org/users/39179/hillal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on the sources from attached link, you should looking for hints in error message.

> Failed to load library
> /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libjoint_value_monitor.so.
> Make sure that you are calling the
> PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the
> library code, and that names are
> consistent between this macro and your
> XML. Error string: Could not load
> library (Poco exception =
> /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libjoint_value_monitor.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZN19joint_value_monitor11joint_value4loadERKN4rviz6ConfigE)

First of all, we know that we have poroblems with **libjoint_value_monitor.so** library which should be located in the **/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libjoint_value_monitor.so** path --- but, it looks good

The library code contains `PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS` macro and names are consistent between this macro and XML --- Ok

Let's check the last sentence with undefined symbol: `_ZN19joint_value_monitor11joint_value4loadERKN4rviz6ConfigE`, so we should check if we have implemented this function. If we can't deduce function name from `_ZN19joint_value_monitor11joint_value4loadERKN4rviz6ConfigE`, we can call:

```
<$:~$ c++filt _ZN19joint_value_monitor11joint_value4loadERKN4rviz6ConfigE
```

where output will be

```
joint_value_monitor::joint_value::load(rviz::Config const&)
```

So the problem is lack of `joint_value_monitor::joint_value::load(rviz::Config const&)` definition.

---

Originally posted by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) with karma: 290 on 2019-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0